# Unable to find SDL2_gfx library on linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, opengl, gcc

I am trying to install gfx2 for using it with SDL2 in C++.

I followed the installation process describe at the [official documentation.](http://www.ferzkopp.net/Software/SDL2_gfx/Docs/html/index.html)

Everything went right except when I started to test the installation success, in the section Test Programs, at the step ./configure I obtain the following result :

`checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for SDL... yes
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for X... libraries , headers 
checking for OpenGL support... yes
checking for OpenGL ES support... no
checking for OpenGL ES2 support... no
checking for pixelColor  in -lSDL2_gfx... no
configure: error: 
*** Unable to find SDL2_gfx library`

I haven't found any similar problem in my research.

Apparently the library is not installed where it is supposed to be (if anywhere), but I do not know where the script is looking.

Any ideas?

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you run `make install` with root privileges e.g. `sudo make install` if logged in as non-root user. Alternatively you can specify library binaries location in `LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable e.g. `export LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:~/sdl2` and headers location in `C_INCLUDE_PATH` variable if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer,

I was indeed with root privileges when I entered the make install command (it gives an error if not).

I tried `export LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib` (destination where the libraries were installed) and `export C_INCLUDE_PATH=$INCLUDE_PATH:/usr/local/include/SDL2/` (But there is only the SDL2 headers here, no trace of gfx).

The result of ./configure is exactly the same as previously.